# MySQL Syntax Error from PHP When Executing Multiple Queries

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

When I execute:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE fname = '$fname'; INSERT INTO people (first_name) VALUES ('$fname')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I receive this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO people (first_name) VALUES ('Draski')' at line 1
```

Where is the syntax error?

Comment: You can only run _one_ query with `mysql_query()`, not multiple. So, make it different function calls. Also, `mysql_` is deprecated, for new code, please use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do run two queries in one statement with the `mysql_*` API. You will have to run them in two separate queries.

You can do it with [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php), however. And since the [`mysql_*` API is deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) you should be using an alternative API like `mysqli_*` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Will select as answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for  multiple queries.